# How to make sequence from specific number?

Tags: ruby

How to make sequence from the beginning of square number and then adding it to the previous result?

```
7 => 49, 56, 63, ...

def make_sequence(number)
  lambda { number*number ??? }
end

num = make_sequence(7)
num.call #=> 49
num.call #=> 56
...
```

Comment: check out Enumerator: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your initial idea using closures I'd write:

```
def make_sequence(n)
  x = n**2 - n
  lambda { x += n }
end

num = make_sequence(7)
p num.call #=> 49
p num.call #=> 56
```

Answer (score 2):

use [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html)

```
def make_sequence(start)
  pos = start**2
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    loop do
      y.yield(pos)
      pos += start
    end
  end
end

seq = make_sequence(7)
seq.next   #=> 49
seq.next   #=> 56

...
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Fiber](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html) version:

```
def make_sequence(num)
  inc = num
  num = num*num
  Fiber.new do
    loop do
      Fiber.yield(num)
      num += inc
    end
  end
end

a = make_sequence(7)
p a.resume  #=> 49
p a.resume  #=> 56
p a.resume  #=> 63
...
```

Comment: I'd keep `num` untouched (be nice with your callers) and update in-place local variables.

Comment: In ruby, reassignment does not change the original variables contents. This code is safe.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the `num = num*num` line. Now the problem is other then: why rebinding instead of creating a new variable? from a mathematical perspective `num = num*num` looks really bad.